# After installing capacitor, circuit is not working anymore

Tags: capacitor, usb

In order to eliminate potential voltage spikes from my wall charger, I added a 6,3V 220µF capacitor to my circuit. A very simplified drawing is below:

[image]

However after installing the capacitor, I am unable to measure any voltage, even after having it powered on for a while. A USB charger is used for this circuit.

What could be the reason for this? Could the capacitor be broken or am I using it wrong?

Comment: A capacitor acts like an open circuit after connecting to a DC supply and reaching steady-state. Effectively, the way it is connected in your circuit, you have a break in your wire.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! It makes a lot more sense now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The capacitor should be in parallel with the load, not in series with it. Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFJ15b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>